# d3.js Histogram does not show columns

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a d3 histogram but the columns are not showing up. I am new to d3 and have hours spent trying to figure it out with no success.

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nallad1985/5MZKK/1/

```
        var formatCount = d3.format(",0f");
        var values = [3866, 3874, 3876, 3887, 3888, 3896, 3897, 3900, 3904, 3908, 3916, 3916];

        var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
                width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([d3.min(values), d3.max(values)])

                .nice()
                .range([0, width]);

        // Generate a histogram using twenty uniformly-spaced bins.
        var data = d3.layout.histogram()
                .bins(x.ticks(20))
                (values);



        var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })])
                .range([height, 0])
                ;



        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom");

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

        bar.append("rect")
                .attr("x", 100)
                .attr("width", x(data[0].dx) - 1)
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });

        bar.append("text")
                .attr("dy", ".75em")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("x", x(data[0].dx) / 2)
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.y); });

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty old, so you probably figured it out, but for the rest of us who cut and paste Mike Bostock's histogram code and can't figure out why it no longer works when the data changes, the issue is how the column width is scaled by the x linear scale.

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([d3.min(values), d3.max(values)])
          .nice()
          .range([0, width]);
```

The linear scale defined by x is cannot be used to transform widths; it can only be safely used to transform locations. (At least not in the way it is being called below -- I a bit of a newbie, there might be methods I don't know about)

```
   .attr("width", x(data[0].dx) - 1)
```

The quickest fix I came up with is

```
   .attr("width", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) - 1)
```

but there is possibly a much more idiomatic solution.

That code works in the example on bl.ocks.org because the domain starts at 0 -- if your domain does not, you cant scale the widths in this way.